# Changing node version using WSL and NVM

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvm

I am developing a web app on windows using nodejs (installed using wsl) and would like to switch to a specific node version due to other teams' compatibilities.
I used the nvm use statement but it did not work.
Any suggestion?

I expect to be able to switch between node versions easily.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddhDa.png)

Please have a look at the attached pic, thanks

Comment: have you tried restarting your console after switching?

Comment: Yes, but nothing changes